# Convert YCCK jpeg to RGB

Tags: c++, rgb, libjpeg, cmyk

I have a jpeg image with the colors encoded in the YCCK color space. I have already decoded it in C++ using libjpeg. How can I convert it to RGB?

Converting it to CMYK would also be useful for me, since I know how to convert from CMYK to RGB using ICC color profiles.

Comment: This page may have what you are looking for: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4799903

Comment: "bug not available" any more in Sun's database

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch15/functn_YCCKToCMYK_JPEG.html#functn_YCCKToCMYK_JPEG).

First, conversion is done into RGB format as:

```
R = Y + 1.402*Cr - 179.456
G = Y - 0.34414*Cb - 0.71414*Cr + 135.45984
B = Y + 1.772*Cb - 226.816
```

After that, conversion to CMYK image is performed as follows:

```
C = 255 – R
M = 255 – G
Y = 255 – B
```

The values of K channel are written without modification.

Comment: I am curious, in this middle step, if we try to reproduce the image as RGB, is there some information going to be discarded?

Comment: Where you able to properly convert YCCK to rgb?

Comment: Outside of this answer; you need CMYK samples and at least ICC color profile to get meaningful RGB to come out. This gives the YCCK to CMYK step as was asked.